# Linear differential equation (integrating factor method)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Currently stuck trying to understood a simple example  of an Integrating Factor Differential equation question:

Solve:

$y' - \frac{1}{x}y = x^{2}$

Clearly the integrating factor is $\frac{1}{x}$

After multiplying by the I.F, the equation becomes:

$\frac{1}{x} (y'-\frac{1}{x}y) = x$

The next step is the one that confuses me, the equation becomes:

$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{y}{x}) = x $

How exactly **was** this step achieved? I have tried rearranging the prior equation but haven't found any success. Is the quotient rule needed? Seems like a leap to me currently.

Comment: $fg'+f'g=(fg)'$ here $f=\dfrac 1x$ and $g=y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product rule:

$fg'+f'g=(fg)'$ here $f=\dfrac 1x$ and $g=y$

Or quotient rule:

$\dfrac {fg'-f'g}{f^2}=\left(\dfrac gf\right)'$ here $f=x$ and $g=y$

$$\implies \left(\dfrac yx\right)'=x$$

---

$$y' - \frac{1}{x}y = x^{2}$$
Multiply by $\dfrac 1x$
$$\dfrac {y'}x - \dfrac y{x^2} = x$$
$$\dfrac 1x  {y'} +\left ( \dfrac 1 x\right)' y = x$$
By the product rule:
$$\left ( \dfrac 1x y\right)'=x$$
Integrate both sides

Comment: I completed my answer hope it helps @HenryM

Comment: @HenryM What you are asking for is the first line of this answer (also the comment).  Expanding the LHS of your last equation by the product rule gives the LHS of your previous equation (and this is exactly what the method of integrating factors always does).

Comment: @JBL Thanks for pointing that out! Makes sense now.